# Swift - UIView Containing UIImageView Containing Image

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, layer, addsubview

I'm trying to create a UIView that has a border color / width, add a subview UIImageView that has a different border color / width, and also has an image inside of all that. So essentially what I want is an image with a white border followed by a blue border.

Right now I'm only seeing the blue border show up. Here is what I am doing:

(Inside of a closure, where outerView is a UIView)

```
        outerView.frame = cell.frame
        outerView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
        outerView.layer.borderWidth = 3.0
        outerView.layer.cornerRadius = outerView.frame.height / 2
        outerView.clipsToBounds = true
        outerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

        let imageView = UIImageView(frame: outerView.frame)
        imageView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        self?.controller?.setupImageView(imageView, cell: cell)
        outerView.addSubview(imageView)
```

(`setupImageView`:)

```
let frame = imageView.frame
imageView.image = imageConstants.imageToDisplay
imageView.clipsToBounds = true
imageView.layer.cornerRadius = frame.height / 2
imageView.layer.borderWidth = 3.0
imageView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
```

If I change it up so the closure just returns me a UIImageView type (outerView is a UIImageView) and pass that straight into the setupImageView(imageView:cell:) function, I'm able to see the image along with a white border.

I'm not sure what I'm missing in order to get both to display.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

outerView and your imageView have the same frame (This mean they have the same height and the same width) the imageView's border is under the outherView's border.

Try this:

```
let outerFrame = outerView.frame
let frame = CGRect(x: outerFrame.origin.x - 3, y: outerFrame.origin.y - 3, width: outerFrame.size.width -6, height: outerFrame.size.height -6)
```

3 because `borderWidth = 3.0`

and:

```
let imageView = UIImageView(frame: frame)
```